# How to update multiple columns in excel using SQL query come formula

Tags: mysql, excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet where I have multiple records stored(around 300). Each record has data in 20 columns. Now I want to update the data of 3 specific columns for all record without updating each record manually, for this I have come up with the following formula:

```
="update student set firstName='"&R2&"' , middleName='"&W2&"' , lastName='"&X2&"' where studentId="&M2&" ;".
```

I don't know if this is right or not. Also I haven't been able to complete understand the use of ampersand. Can somebody explain the referencing using ampersand? Hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: What's wrong with it? What does your formula output?

Comment: the output is that it shows the same data in all the rows, also i am not sure if I have to use '$' or '&'. I am getting confused about the working of this formula. I am not an active excel user so please don't mind if I ask something stupid.

Comment: '&' concatenates strings '$' fixes the cell reference. Are the cell references the same in all the rows?

Comment: I understand that much but I don't think '&' is concatenate in this update formula, although I have fixed the issue with my query, it was causing problem because I was using an older version. The thing is I still don't understand the concept and working of this update formula.